# How to retrieve data from Excel file using OleDbConnection

Tags: c#, .net, oledb, com-interop

the thing is that I need to select only 2 columns from the data in Excel, so i went on using sql for retrieving the data from the Excel file. But this time i keep getting "failed to create file" error and this happens when i try to open my connection. Why is it trying to create a file ?

my code:

```
public void ReadExcelFile()
{
    string connectionString = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ExcelConnection"].ConnectionString.Replace("'", "\""), "@C:/Temp/Copy.xlsx");
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            string sqlCmd = "SELECT  * FROM [Ark1$]";
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlCmd, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR in ReadExcelFile() method. Error Message : " + exception.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: The slashes in your file path are backwards.

Comment: It's very likely the problem is in the connection string but we can't say... can you post it?

Comment: `<add name="ExcelConnection" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties= Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;"/>`

Comment: in my Connectionstring ?

Comment: Yeah. Is there only one worksheet in the workbook?

Comment: there is more than one. but the others are empty. I get an error stating "Could not find installable ISAM" when i use IMEX=1

Comment: remove "Xml" from the properties string

Comment: didn't help.. I have also tried to set the platform to be 86X cuz i read that the oleDBconenction only has en 86X driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

** EDITED **

Test it like this:-

```
string filename = "@C:\Temp\Copy.xlsx";

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + 
filename + ";Extended Properties=\Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"");
```

Comment: I get an error stating "Could not find installable ISAM" when i use IMEX=1

Comment: Please test this, Its what I have used in a similar project and it works fine for me.

Comment: i get this error: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.Seems like i need to install something? cuz this method should work without so much hassle.

Comment: Sorry make that 12.0, not 4.0

Comment: No Problem, got there in the end.

Answer (score 0):

To configure OleBConnection for read Excel file try this:

```
string filename = "@C:\Temp\Copy.xlsx";       

OleDbConnection connection =new OleDbConnection(
                         "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='"+filename+"';"+
                         "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
```